# Cannot drop a column in PostgreSQL

Tags: django, database, postgresql

I am pretty new in PostgreSQL and only know basic operations about database. I have a database called neuro_db with username neuro_user. Now I found I cannot delete a column in a table from neuro_db.

After I tried `psql neuro_db` in ubuntu 14.04, I got in a command line started with `neuro_db=#`. The `\d` command would show a table like this:

```
                         List of relations
 Schema |               Name                |   Type   |   Owner
--------+-----------------------------------+----------+------------
 public | auth_group                        | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_group_id_seq                 | sequence | neuro_user
 public | auth_group_permissions            | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_group_permissions_id_seq     | sequence | neuro_user
 public | auth_permission                   | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_permission_id_seq            | sequence | neuro_user
 public | auth_user                         | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_user_groups                  | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_user_groups_id_seq           | sequence | neuro_user
 public | auth_user_id_seq                  | sequence | neuro_user
 public | auth_user_user_permissions        | table    | neuro_user
 public | auth_user_user_permissions_id_seq | sequence | neuro_user
 public | django_admin_log                  | table    | neuro_user
 public | django_admin_log_id_seq           | sequence | neuro_user
 public | django_content_type               | table    | neuro_user
 public | django_content_type_id_seq        | sequence | neuro_user
 public | django_migrations                 | table    | neuro_user
 public | django_migrations_id_seq          | sequence | neuro_user
 public | django_session                    | table    | neuro_user
 public | neuro_category                    | table    | neuro_user
 public | neuro_category_id_seq             | sequence | neuro_user
 public | neuro_page                        | table    | neuro_user
 public | neuro_page_id_seq                 | sequence | neuro_user
(23 rows)
```

I wanted to edit the table "neuro_page" and after typing `\d neuro_page`
, it will show this table:

```
                                   Table "public.neuro_page"
   Column    |          Type          |                        Modifiers
-------------+------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
 id          | integer                | not null default      nextval('neuro_page_id_seq'::regclass)
 category_id | integer                | not null
 title       | character varying(128) | not null
 text        | text                   | not null
 url         | character varying(200) | not null
 photo       | character varying(100) | not null
 order       | character varying(128) | not null
 date        | date                   | not null
 views       | integer                | not null
 likes       | integer                | not null
```

I wanted to delete the "order" column in this table so I tried typed `ALTER TABLE neuro_page DROP COLUMN order` right after the `neuro_db=#` line, but nothing happened. There was also nothing after trying `ALTER TABLE neuro_page` and `DROP COLUMN order` respectively. The "order" column is still there! And no error information!

I have also searched on google for the answer but found nothing. I think I have followed the normal operations in database but can not drop a single column in a table. There is no foreign key for "order" column.

I'd be very greatful if anyone can help me with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using Django 1.7+, you should be using migrations, so you shouldn't have to drop columns manually. If you drop the column manually, you risk your models and migrations getting out of sync with your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the column name order in backticks because order is a keyword (e.g. `order by 'column_name'`). Make sure you are using a semicolon to show the end of the command:

```
ALTER TABLE neuro_page DROP COLUMN `order`;
```

Comment: Thanks Alasdair！I missed the semicolon...As you said, I tried only the migrations first, but when I added another element, it raised a IntegrityError about "null value in column 'order' violates not-null constraint". That makes me want to drop the whole "order" column in database.

Comment: And `ALTER TABLE neuro_page DROP COLUMN order;`command causes a `syntax error at or near "order"` error...

Comment: You need to escape 'order' in backticks. You should really get the migrations working instead of dropping columns manually. I can't offer any specific advice because I don't know what you've done. After removing the field from your model, creat a migration with `makemigrations`, then perform the migration with `migrate`.

Comment: Thanks! Now it works. And also migrations command works well.

Comment: It's great that you are learning to do it on the command line.. but you should give the graphical postgres client pgadmin3 a try, it is much much easier sometimes.  You can still enter your sql manually or use the GUI interface.. but the GUI interface shows you the SQL it is about to execute so that you can copy it into a script, learn from it, modify it...